# How to get filepath of a file in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have a project which is in an Azure Service Fabric Solution. How can I get specific full filepath of a content file? The content file is in the same folder with my source code.

What I tried:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

But it turns out:

C:\SfDevCluster\Data_App_Node_4\ABCXYZType_App126\ABCXYZPkg.Code.1.0.0\ABCXYZ.dll
 This is a file in bin/debug folder

Comment: So, what is wrong with that path? It is the full path. That is where the packages are deployed to. What did you expect?

Comment: Sorry I will edit the question for clarity. The path I receive is in the bin/debug folder. What I want is a content file that is in source code folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the location of content files you can use:

```
var path = Path.Combine(
            FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext().GetCodePackageObject("Code").Path,
            "Readme.txt");

ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this.Context, File.ReadAllText(path));
```

provided that the file Readme.txt has the Build Action is set to "Content" and the Copy to Output Directory setting is set to something else than "do not copy".